# Change Scroll Wheel Speed for Logitech M570

Tags: mouse, logitech, scrolling, xinput

If I do `xinput list-props "Logitech M570"` I get

```
Device 'Logitech M570':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (277):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (278):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (279):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (280):   0, 0, 10
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (281):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (282): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (283): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (284):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (285):    0
    libinput Rotation Angle (286):  0.000000
    libinput Rotation Angle Default (287):  0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (288): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (289): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (290):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (291):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (292):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (293): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (294): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (262): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (263):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (264):    0, 0
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (266):    1133, 4136
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (295):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (296):   1
```

I tried to change some of the scrolling settings but they all give this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-MacBookPro:~$ sudo xinput set-prop "Logitech M570" 'libinput Scroll Methods Available' 0 0 2
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
ubuntu@ubuntu-MacBookPro:~$ sudo xinput set-prop "Logitech M570" 'libinput Scroll Methods Available' 0 0 1
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
```

except `libinput Scroll Method Enabled` which was at `0 0 0` originally and I changed it to `0 0 10` but that didn't do anything for the mouse speed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this as root, this may be the cause of your problems.

You might want to try this approach instead:

1. Identify your device with
   `xinput list`

which should return a list of the devices along with their id, e.g.:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

In my case, the device I want to edit is the Logitech mouse, id=9.

2. Now you can proceed to query its properties:

`xinput list-props 9`

this should yield something like:

```
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (294):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (295):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (296):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (297):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (298):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (299): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (300): 2
    ...
```

Now you have all you need to change some property value, e.g.:

`xinput set-prop 9 'libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled' 1`

Please note this is done as your current logged in user, not root: it's your user who is using a mouse.

If for some reason you need to run this at boot time, put it into `/etc/profile`